# Is preprocessor blindly replace the defines?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a class that has a member function called `SendMessage`. No member function named SendMessageA exists in the project.
Project is multibite, so I have a define

`#define SendMessage  SendMessageA`

If I call `SendMessage` somewhere in that class, will my project call `SendMessage` or `SendMessageA` ?

If the replace is made by preprocessor,the project should not compile. Right ?
But I see in a dump that `SendMessageA` is called ... end eip register is not in any VAD

**EDIT**

A more specific question: is preprocessor blindly replace the defines ? or first checks for a match in the class ?

Comment: I'd say you're in for a World of Pain...

Comment: Updated my answer, see below.

Comment: Are you saying that **you** have this define (why?) or are you referring to the define from the windows headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How C++ preprocessor works

In case of `#define A B` preprocessor replaces ALL occurences of `A` with `B`. It is pure substitution.

> Will my project call `SendMessage` or `SendMessageA` ?

Your project will call either `SendMessageA` or `SendMessageW` - depending on whether it was compiled with unicode support or not. There's no `SendMessage` function - it doesn't exist.

> f the replace is made the project should not compile.

SendMessageA is declared within `<widnows.h>` (or in a header that is included from windows.h) - somewhere, and its linking info is within one of base system libraries (User32.lib, I think). If you're on windows, there's a very good chance `<windows.h>` is `#included` from somewhere, and corresponding *.lib is already in linker dependencies.

--EDIT--

> A more specific question: is preprocessor blindly replace the defines ?

Yes, preprocessor *blindly* replaces defines. For non-blind replacement you have templates, but they have their own limitations. Some thing that can be done with preprocessor cannot be done with templates and vice versa. Preprocessor have stringize operator, templates have type-checking and metaprogramming.

> My problem is why sometimes the member function SendMessage is called because the code works (most of the time)

If you have `SendMessage` *method* in your code (BAD idea on windows platform - clashes with system macro, replace with `sendMessage()` or use different name, because even namespaces won't help you to avoid omnipresent preprocessor) your method (not `SendMessageA`/`SendMessageW`) will be called from *.cpp ONLY if `<windows.h>` was not included in that *.cpp.

Compiler operates at one file at a time, and has no knowledge of thing that go on in other files, so if there's no `<windows.h>` `#included`, **your** method will be called, because preprocessor won't have any knowledge about `SendMessage` `#define` (from `<windows.h>`). If `<windows.h>` is included, then ALL occurences of `SendMessage` will be replaced with `SendMessageA`/`SendMessageW`, because preprocessor does its job first.

One possible solution in your situation would be to avoid using naming convention similar to the one in Win API. I.e. make sure that function names don't start with capital letter. That'll solve many problems, but you'll still get minor trouble from `min`/`max` macros.

Comment: I don't agree with "if the replace is made the project should not compile." We have a valid candidate(SendMesageA) that can be called. My problem is **why sometimes the member function SendMessage is called** because the code works (most of the time).

Answer (score 3):

The Preprocessor runs through your code before compilation.
So any SendMessage would be converted into a SendMessageA. The compiler will then look for a function called SendMessageA and call it.

Comment: ok, but why is working "sometimes" ? there are many calls to sendMessage

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor works as a text macro processor. If a macro is defined, all occurrences of the macro are replaced with it's definition.

```
#define blabla some_real_stuff

struct blabla /* blabla will be replaced with some_real_stuff */
{
   void method();
};

int main()
{
   some_real_stuff x;
   x.method();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows API, there are the two functions SendMessageA and SendMessageW. You will be calling one of these two, depending on what #defines you have in your program.
Are you sure that is not what happens?

Edit: oh wait. Is your `#define SendMessage SendMessageA` before the definition of the SendMessage member function in your source? If so, the compiler will simply use SendMessageA for the name of the member. Otherwise, your function will be SendMessage, but the rest of your program will call the built in Windows function SendMessageA.

If you have many source files, maybe some of them will know about the #define, while others won't.

My recommendation is to rename the member function to something else and dispense with the #define.

Comment: the definition is the one from Windef.h. I am surprised that program somehow works. I guess this is my question. Why ?

Comment: To answer that, we'd have to see the source. With the #define in the right place, the member function will simply be named SendMessageA and it will be called from the rest of the program. Otherwise, some parts may call SendMessage, i.e. the windef one.